# Fix %s sql query in python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector-python

Python refuses to execute an sql query

I want to execute an insert sql query with python language in Pycharm.
An error is launched after executing the code below:

```
import mysql.connector

stock = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="admin2020",
  database="stock"
)

sql = "INSERT INTO produit(code, nom, prix_unitaire, tva, quantite) VALUES(%s,%s,%f,%f,%d)"
valeurs = ("LAM","lampe",0.9,0.19,10)
mycursor = stock.cursor()
mycursor.execute(sql, valeurs)
```

The error message is:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Comment: due to dbapi only `%s` is allowed

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing `%s` used as a [*parameter marker*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) for a query, and `%s` (`%d`, `%f`, etc) used in Python [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting). In your queries you should use just `%s`, the database driver will format the query for you:

```
sql = ("INSERT INTO produit(code, nom, prix_unitaire, tva, quantite) "
       "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")
valeurs = ("LAM", "lampe", 0.9, 0.19, 10)
mycursor.execute(sql, valeurs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
sql = "INSERT INTO produit(code, nom, prix_unitaire, tva, quantite) VALUES(%s,%s,%f,%f,%d)"%("LAM","lampe",0.9,0.19,10)

    mycursor = stock.cursor()
    mycursor.execute(sql)
```